# sort.Sort() vs slices.Sort()

Tags: sorting, go, slice

Given a `[]int`, e.g: `is := []int{2, 4, 1, 3}`

Can sort via:

1. `sort.Sort()`, e.g:

   ```
   sort.Sort(sort.IntSlice(is))
   ```
2. `slices.Sort()`, e,g:

   ```
   slices.Sort(is)
   ```

I know `slices.Sort()` is experience, from `"golang.org/x/exp/slices"`.
Other than that, is there any difference when sort an `[]int`, and which is preferred usually?

Comment: To sort []int use neither but sort.Ints.

Answer (score 2):

The article "[SORTING STRINGS IN GO, FAST & SLOW](https://aead.dev/news/sort-strings/)" from [Andreas Auernhammer](https://aead.dev/) lays out the difference between the two packages:

> The difference between the [`sort`](https://pkg.go.dev/sort) and the [`slices`](https://pkg.go.dev/slices) package is that:
>
> - `sort` uses a `Less(i, j int) bool` function for comparison, while
> - `slices` uses a `Cmp func(a,b T) int`.
>
> But sorting an `[]int` with the slices package is about 70% faster than the `sort` package.

Note: the article is about sorting string:

> So, how is it possible that sorting numbers is faster, but sorting strings is slower?
> Because of [`strings.Compare`](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.21.3:src/strings/compare.go;l=13): The three-way string comparison may compare two strings twice while the `sort` package compares two strings only once and the compiler is not smart enough (yet) to replace this pattern with a single function call.

But for `int`, as the [source code of `sort.Ints()`](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.21.3:src/sort/sort.go;l=164-165) shows:

```golang
// Ints sorts a slice of ints in increasing order.
//
// Note: consider using the newer slices.Sort function, which runs faster.
func Ints(x []int) { Sort(IntSlice(x)) }
```

In that case, [`slices.Sort[S ~[]E, E cmp.Ordered](x S)`](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.21.3:src/slices/sort.go;l=14) remains the new best choice.